# Specific financial term for a type of amount

Tags: word-request, terminology

Let's say I take someone to court and I require him to pay me 20k in damages.
But the court/judge/insurance company decides that the real value was 14k and that's they'll pay me.

What are the proper formal terms for these amounts? The kind of terms I would see on paperwork. Eg.:
20k = Requested amount
14k = ???

I'm thinking something along terms

Agreed amount, Settled amount, credited amount

EDIT: This doesn't have to be just for damages, but if I inherit a part of inheritance and my sister another. The amount I'm about to receive will be refered to as…?

Comment: I think it is best to ask this here: https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've voted to close on the grounds that this question is too broad.  You've given us several rather different scenarios (inheritance, insurance company, judge) and each scenario would have a different adjective modifying **amount**. What you seem to be asking for is a word that means "what I ended up getting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use **settlement**. The [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/settlement) has several examples.

> unions succeeded in reaching a pay settlement
>
> the award was made as an out-of-court settlement by the driver's
>   insurance firm
>
> inheritance tax could be due if you make a substantial gift or
>   settlement and then die within the following seven years
>
> most suppliers will offer early settlement discounts

EDIT:

The court's *decision* was its [**judgement** or **judgment**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/judgement).

The settlement can also be referred to as the amount [**awarded**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/award).

The "requested amount" in the question could be the [**amount claimed**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/claim).

Comment: So the amount would be called Settled amount?

Comment: But how do you apply **settlement** in the inheritance example?

Comment: @Zikato I edited the answer.

Comment: -1 for "settlement" and +1 for *awarded* and *judgment*. There is no "settlement" per se here, if the insurance company decides or a judge decides what the amount will be.

Comment: @Mattias sorry I did not notice that term in your answer, until after I had edited this answer, although I see now that the term "awarded" did appear in your original one-liner, whose answer was **damages**.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general term, as it depends on the situation and circumstances.

If you're talking about damages, then the answer would be "awarded".

[Damages](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/damages):

> Monetary compensation that is awarded by a court in a civil action to
>   an individual who has been injured through the wrongful conduct of
>   another party.

If you're talking about an inheritance the amount you receive is the one you're bequeathed. But that term can't be used in any other situation.

All your examples (Agreed amount, Settled amount, credited amount) would be suitable for various situations, depending on what the amount was regarding and how it was decided upon.

Comment: I wanted a more generic answer, not just for damages. I'll edit my question.